# PCRE: ^|$ and \A|\Z?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

In PCRE, what's the difference between:

- **`^`** and **`\A`**, and
- **`$`** and **`\Z`**?

I remember reading there was a subtle difference, but can't recall exactly what it was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, there is no difference between the two, they both signify the start or end of the string. If, however, you use the `m` modifier, then `^` and `$` will match the start and end of lines, respectively.

Comment: Also note that `$` and `\Z` (uppercase Z) will match before a newline at the end of the string, whereas the `\z` (lowercase Z) matches only at the very end of the string.

Comment: @ridgerunner: Nice: http://codepad.org/4pZVzWjf! I didn't even knew `\z` existed.